# Devise inline errors stop showing up when overriding update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, devise, simple-form

Using Rails 3.2, Devise 3.5.1, SimpleForm

I'm using a custom update method in Devise:

```
def update
    resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    resource_updated = update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
    if resource_updated
      sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
      redirect_to edit_member_registration_path, notice: "Updated successfully"
    else
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      redirect_to edit_member_registration_path, alert: resource.errors.full_messages
    end
end
```

This is my form code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
<% end %>
```

Everything works fine, but when there are validation errors, I can't figure out why they are only showing up in the Flash message and not inline.

[image]

---

When I removed the custom update function, I get this behavior, which is exactly what I want:

---

[image]

Is there something wrong with my update function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you redirect, probably the `resource` are being reloaded and getting a cleaned `errors`
Instead of redirect, try

```
if resource_updated
  sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
  redirect_to edit_member_registration_path, notice: "Updated successfully"
else
  clean_up_passwords(resource)
  respond_with resource
end
```

The Responder should render the appropriate flash message, and will let the resource object untouched with the `errors` attribute, necessary to simple_form be aware that has some error

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense, any idea how I could have it redirect to a custom path?

Comment: Did you try `respond_with`? I think it will render the original page with the resource with errors. If not, you could use `render` instead of `redirect_to`